# Автоматическая генерация и создание страниц через MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: возможно ли автоматически сгенерировать html страницу посредством внесения в бд данных (т.е например я написал новую статью и  внес её содержание в бд)

в таблице колонки: //content//  - текст статьи
                  //name//    -название статьи
                  //autor//  -автор
                  //url//    -адрес этой самой страницы со статьёй :-)

соответствееноо они все заполнены моими новыми внесееными данными

(Допустим, шаблон страницы уже имеется)

Comment: Вы сами поставили тег php, собственно php для того и предназначен, что бы создавать html страницы на основении неких данных, которые совершенно спокойно могут браться из БД. Так что "Да, возможно"

Comment: А как это можно осуществить, например какой принцип работы будет

Comment: прочитать значение из БД и напечатать его с помощью print

Comment: А как будет проходить генерация страницы?

Comment: все что php печатает web-сервер отдает клиенту, а тот получает это и это для него html. если надо писать в файл никто не мешает печатать в файл

Comment: Гляньте шаблонизаторы. https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php / http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое - поставить OpenServer (или Денвер, или ещё какой-нибудь похожий набор.).

В него входит:

1. apache - вебсервер. Эмуляция сервера. Создаёт локальные сайты для обращения из **браузера**.
2. Mysql сервер - система управления базой данных. (также там приложена Heidi - очень удобная, но постоянно зависающая программка, с помощью которой можно создавать в mysql базы, таблицы, делать первоначальное заполнение)
3. php

После установки нужно создать сайт, базу данных и начать писать код на php.

Apache передаёт запросы в php, там они разбираются и выполняется изменение базы, вывод данных.